# How to properly build a Vue component library using Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've done my research and found some questions about building a vue component library using vuetify. However none of them answered my issue.

After building the library and adding it to my app, the app throws errors of unknown custom elements. These elements are the vuetify ones.

Here is my small lib:
https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-water-f79hp

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the Vuetify components and add them to the `components` section of your own components.

For example:

```html
<script>
import VFileInput from 'vuetify/something'

export default {
  name: 'FormParser',
  components: {
    VFileInput
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I tried that. Plus, that component works fine in development.